# Split Persian Date Numbers Form Words in Java

Tags: java, regex, date, numbers, words

I want to **split Persian Date number from stick words** in **java.** 
My string is like : "۰۱/۰۷/۱۳۹۵سعید"

I search too much, But I cant find appropriate one, that works for me!! 
In addition *Date format might completely Wrong*, its **important** to separate word from numbers.

I want to reach some thing Like "۰۱/۰۷/۱۳۹۵ سعید"

Comment: Are you trying to separate all numbers from adjoining letters?  Or just numbers that are part of a date in day/month/year format?  Also, isn't it more common to write Persian dates as year/month/day?

Comment: I want to seprate all numbers, but in this case it is date, so I appreciate solution. Yes it is common but I have to use date in this format

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my solution.  It adds spaces to the String as you requested.  In my `main` method, I give `سعید۰۱/۰۷/۱۳۹۵سعید` as input and get `سعید ۰۱/۰۷/۱۳۹۵ سعید` printed on the console.

```
public class StringPadder {

    private static final String BETWEEN_NUMBER_AND_LETTER = "(?<=\\p{IsDigit})(?=\\p{IsAlphabetic})";
    private static final String BETWEEN_LETTER_AND_NUMBER = "(?<=\\p{IsAlphabetic})(?=\\p{IsDigit})";

    public static String addSpaces(String toPad) {
        return toPad.replaceAll(BETWEEN_NUMBER_AND_LETTER, " ").replaceAll(BETWEEN_LETTER_AND_NUMBER, " ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String toTest =  "سعید۰۱/۰۷/۱۳۹۵سعید";
        System.out.println(addSpaces(toTest));

    }
}
```

This works by some regular expression tricks.

- The expression `\p{IsDigit}` matches a digit in *any* alphabet; so not just 0-9, but also Arabic/Persian numbers, Devanagari numbers and so on.
- The expression `\p{IsAlphabetic}` matches a letter in *any* alphabet; so not just A-Z and a-z but also the Arabic/Persian alphabet and other alphabets.
- When you see `(?<=X)` in a regular expression, it means that the match you're looking for must be *preceded* by something that matches `X`, but the match for `X` won't be part of the match that you find.  This is called a "lookbehind", because it says "look behind what you're matching, and see if it's `X`".
- When you see `(?=X)` in a regular expression, it means that the match you're looking for must be *followed* by something that matches `X`, but the match for `X` won't be part of the match that you find.  This is called a "lookahead", because it says "look ahead of what you're matching, and see if it's `X`".

Putting all that together, I've included two regular expressions in the code, namely `BETWEEN_NUMBER_AND_LETTER` and `BETWEEN_LETTER_AND_NUMBER`.  Each of these matches nothing at all, because they contain no characters that actually match anything.  But each one has a lookbehind and a lookahead.  So `BETWEEN_NUMBER_AND_LETTER` matches "nothing at all" with a number before it and a letter after it; and `BETWEEN_LETTER_AND_NUMBER` matches "nothing at all" with a letter before it and a number after it.

What you need to do is to replace either of those nothings with a space, because that will separate any letter from any number, provided they were consecutive characters in the original `String`.  That's what my `addSpaces` method does - it first puts a space at any point in the `String` where there was a number immediately followed by a letter, then it puts a space at any point where there was a letter immediately followed by a number.

My test case, in `main` demonstrates that this is what you required.